# Difference between two regex pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I my application I am using below regex for pattern matching.

**Original Pattern :**

```
/(\w+\.){2,}/ig
```

Above pattern added in one array. Since this pattern has comma ( , ) after 2, creating problem in some environment.

As we know below concept in regex  :

```
 {n} - matches n times
 {n, m} - matches at least n times, but not more than m times
```

So I have removed comma present after 2, because in above pattern no value exist after comma.

**Pattern after removing comma :**

```
/(\w+\.){2}/ig
```

As per above change i have resolved environment problem which i was facing earlier.

So here, I just wanted to know that by removing comma after 2 creates any problem while matching, for above given case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{2}` means match if it appears exactly 2 times, and `{2,}` means 2 times or above. Depending on the usage, this may or may not matter.

For example, if you want to validate whether the string contains 2 or more `\w+\.`, then the comma doesn't matter. However, if you want to replace those 2 or more `\w+\.` with something else, the comma will affect the result.

```
'foo.bar.baz.'.replace(/(\w+\.){2}/ig, '~') == '~baz.'
'foo.bar.baz.'.replace(/(\w+\.){2,}/ig, '~') == '~'
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny your info helps me lot

Answer (score 1):

{2,} means two or more. There is no max limit.
With this, {0,} is the same as *, and {1,} is the same as +

To summarize:

```
{n} match n times
{n,m} match at least n times, but not more than m times
{n,} match at least n times
```

Refer [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for details